# Hidden Div takes space before Javascript switch with other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have 2 Div's that when I press a button they swich between them using javascript .

The problem is that before I press the button the hidden div takes space and messes the layout .

I attached the snippet

```js
function switchVisible() {
  if (document.getElementById('1')) {

    if (document.getElementById('1').style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();" </button>
<div id="1">
  some content
</div> 

<div id="2" class="inner border">
  some content 2
</div>
```

Comment: Am hide one of the dives with css ? taht way at the begining you will see just one

Answer (score 1):

You've just to hide it for the first time using :

```
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
```

Or also using inline style (NOT recommended):

```
<div id="2" class="inner border" style='display:none'>
```

Hope this helps.

```js
document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';

function switchVisible() {
  if (document.getElementById('1')) {

    if (document.getElementById('1').style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('2').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();" </button>
<div id="1">
  some content
</div> 

<div id="2" class="inner border">
  some content 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
  div#2 {display: none;}
</style>
```